# Separate numbers from letters and special characters and calculate sum

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove special characters and letters from an array and calculate the sum of the remaining integers in the array, in JavaScript.

```js
const arr = ["13,d42", "d44f2", "1g5", "1c42"];

            let numbersOnly = (val) => {
                if (typeof val === "number") {
                    // replace number with string to get only string values in an array.
                    return val;
                } else {
                    let temp = val.split("");
                    // document.write(temp);
                    let newArr = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                        if (typeof temp[i].parseInt() === 'number') {
                            document.write(i)
                            newArr.push(temp[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    // return newArr;
                    // document.write(newArr)
                }
            };

            let numbers = arr.map(numbersOnly).reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
            document.write(numbers);
```

Comment: So what result do you want for the array you show?

Answer (score 2):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the array. For each string find the numbers using [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a simple [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) that array into one string, and then coerce it to a number.

```js
const arr = ['13,d42', 'd44f2', '1g5', '1c42'];

const sum = arr.reduce((sum, str) => {
  const num = Number(str.match(/\d/g).join(''));
  return sum + num;
}, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Sidenote: you probably shouldn't be using `document.write`:

> ⚠ Warning: [Use of the `document.write()` method is strongly discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

Comment: It gives answer 33 which is not equal to exact answer 1941

Comment: @MuhammadAsif I misunderstood what your expected output was. The answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

> 1941 is correct answere. because "13,d42" is first element of the array. returns 1342

```
const arr = ["13,d42", "d44f2", "1g5", "1c42"];

console.log(arr.map(a => +a.match(/\d+/g).join('')).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));  // 1941 => the sum of [ 1342, 442, 15, 142 ]
```

Comment: 1941 is correct answere. because "13,d42" is first element of the array. returns 1342

Comment: @MuhammadAsif, thanks for your attention. Please check out my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you?

```js
const arr = ["13,d42", "d44f2", "1g5", "1c42"];
const onlyNumbers = arr
    .map((value) => value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")) // get just numbers
    .reduce((pv, cv) => parseInt(pv) + parseInt(cv)); // add up the numbers
console.log(onlyNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created **getNumber** which accepts a string as parameter and return the number which its contain.

For example if we pass "13,d42" so it will gonna return us 1342 as number.

And my another function **getTotalSum** will call the function for all the string and do some of all numbers which **getNumber** return;

```
const arr = ["13,d42", "d44f2", "1g5", "1c42"];

const getNumber = (numberString) => {
let numberRes = '';
for(let i = 0; i< numberString.length;i++){
    if(!isNaN(parseFloat(numberString[i]))){
        numberRes += numberString[i]; 
    }
}
return parseFloat(numberRes);
}

const getTotalSum = (arr) => {
let sum = 0;
arr.forEach(el =>{
sum += getNumber(el)
});
return sum;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple if you only want to parse each individual string in the array.

```js
const arr = ["13,d42", "d44f2", "1g5", "1c42"];

const numbersOnly = (val) => {
  const re = /\D/g;
  return parseInt(val.replaceAll(re, ""));
}

let numbers = arr.map(numbersOnly).reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
console.log(numbers);
```

But more importantly what answer are you desiring? Are you treating "13,d42" as 13,42 or 1342?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array#map` with a regular expression to replace all special characters and letters then use `+` to convert from `string` to `numeric`. Finally, use `Array#reduce` to add the numbers to get the sum.

```js
const arr = ["13,d42", "d44f2", "1g5", "1c42"],

      output = arr
      .map(item => +item.replace(/[^\d]+/g,''))
      .reduce(
          (sum,item) => sum + item,0
      );
      
console.log( output );
```

**Alternatively ...**

You can do it without `Array#map` as follows:

```js
const arr = ["13,d42", "d44f2", "1g5", "1c42"],

      output = arr
      .reduce(
          (sum,item) => sum + +item.replace(/[^\d]+/g,''),0
      );
      
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
// Fn to remove numeric part from input string
const stripNonNumeric=(str)=>{return str.replace(/\D/g,'');}

let input =  ["13,d42", "d44f2", "1g5", "1c42"];
// Convert array to numeric array
let numericArray=input.map(item=>(Number(stripNonNumeric(item))))
// Sum array elements
const sum = numericArray.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);    
console.log(sum);
```